# how to slice numpy array with unknown number of column?

Tags: python, arrays, csv, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I want to slice 2d numpy array to my choice of index. For example, I have this `one.csv`

```
111,222,333,444
1,2,3,4
```

I want to slice it into for example

```
XX = array([[ 111.,  222.,  333.],
            [   1.,    2.,    3.]])

YY = array([ 444.,    4.])
```

Let say that I do not know how many index are there, so for `XX` and `YY` I did

```
import numpy

data = numpy.loadtxt('one.csv', delimiter=",")


XX = data[:,0:len(data)]
YY = data[:,len(data)]
```

both `XX` and `YY` resulted as follows

```
# XX
array([[ 111.,  222.],
       [   1.,    2.]])

# YY
array([ 333.,    3.])
```

How do I solve this? Is there any choice other than using `len(data)` ?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: But here `len(data)` is the **number of rows**.

Comment: You can get the number of columns from `.shape` attribute: `data.shape[1]` will give you the number of columns read

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem yes. I just realized that `len(data)` is the number of rows. Thank you for your answer.
@EdChum Thank you for your answer. It is a good reference to me. But for this specific case, I want to input the file, manipulate it from 1st until the second last column without have to find the number of columns read. Thank you again. =)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For your specific example, use this:

```
# all rows, and all columns but the last
XX = data[:, 0:-1]

# all rows and only the last column
YY = data[:, -1]
```

But in general, you can get the shape of the array `data` with `data.shape` and slice the columns as needed.